# there a way to have <lightning:accordion> not have a default section open on page load?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, accordion

There a way to have  not have a default section open on page load? Such as when the page loads all sections are closed and will only open when clicked ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are looking for lightning accordian with mutiple section open where you have the choice to provide which section should be opened initially you can provide an empty list which will make all section closed initially,

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:attribute name="activeSections" type="List" default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="activeSectionsMessage" type="String" default="" />

    <p>{! v.activeSectionsMessage }</p>

    <lightning:accordion
        allowMultipleSectionsOpen="true"
        onsectiontoggle="{! c.handleSectionToggle }"
        activeSectionName="{! v.activeSections }" >
        <lightning:accordionSection name="A" label="Accordion Title A">
            <aura:set attribute="actions">
                <lightning:buttonMenu aura:id="menu" alternativeText="Show menu" menuAlignment="right" iconSize="x-small">
                    <lightning:menuItem value="New" label="Menu Item One" />
                    <lightning:menuItem value="Edit" label="Menu Item Two" />
                </lightning:buttonMenu>
            </aura:set>
            <aura:set attribute="body">
                <p>This is the content area for section A.</p>
                <p>.</p>
                <p>.</p>
                <p>.</p>
                <p>The section height expands to fit your content.</p>
            </aura:set>
        </lightning:accordionSection>
        <lightning:accordionSection name="B" label="Accordion Title B">
                <p>This is the content area for section B.</p>
                <p>.</p>
                <p>.</p>
                <p>.</p>
                <p>The section height expands to fit your content.</p>
        </lightning:accordionSection>
        <lightning:accordionSection name="C" label="Accordion Title C">
                <p>This is the content area for section C.</p>
                <p>.</p>
                <p>.</p>
                <p>.</p>
                <p>The section height expands to fit your content.</p>
        </lightning:accordionSection>
    </lightning:accordion>
</aura:component>
```

in above code you can provide any value to "activeSections" attribute like

```
 <aura:attribute name="activeSections" type="List" default="['A','C']" />
```

to keep A and c Opened or empty to keep all closed.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:accordion/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleAccordionMultiple

Comment: So, if the list is blank will all section remain closed?

Comment: @manjit5190 yes empty like <aura:attribute name="activeSections" type="List" default="" /> and it will remain closed unitl you click and expand them